# Member access in nested struct with pointers. Arrow operator equivalent

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Given example is part of the code of a doubly linked list.
Lets say that I have the following two structs with given typedefs.

```
 typedef struct dplist dplist_t;
 typedef struct dplist_node dplist_node_t;

 struct dplist_node {
   dplist_node_t * prev, * next;
   element_t element;
 };

 struct dplist {
   dplist_node_t * head;
 };
```

And I have the following code in my main function:

```
 void main()
 {
     dplist_t * list;
     dplist_node_t *node_one, *node_two;

     //the arrow equivalent of the assignment
     list->head = node_one;
     list->head->next = node_two;
 }
```

I know that the 'point' equivalent of the node_one assignment is:

```
 (*list).head = node_one;
```

But when I try to find the 'point' equivalent of the node_two assignment all the following variations seem to be wrong:

```
 (*list).(*head).next = node_two;
 (*list).*head.next = node_two;
 (*list).head.next = node_two;
```

Does anyone know the correct way to write this statement?

Comment: `(*(*list).head).next = node_two;`.

Comment: You should be getting a segfault from calling `list->head->next = node_two;` because `head` points to `node_one` and `node_one` is an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: @Rogus this is just an example, I just wrote this out quickly without compiling or anything to show the idea behind the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list->head->next = node_two;` can be written as

```
(*(list->head)).next = node_two;
```

which can be re written as

```
(*((*list).head)).next = node_two;
```

Comment: Why are the double parenthesis in the second line needed? (the double pair around *list.head. I tested according to @willys 's answer in a comment to my original question and this seems to work fine as well.

Comment: @TheAlPaca02; It's just for clarity. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

Should be "(*(*list).head).next = node_two;".

. I am presuming you deliberately missed the lines that would allocate the memory for your list/nodes (list = malloc(...)) to keep the problem short.

. Using the "." is an indication to the compiler to reach the data-member as an offset from a known location/offset and the "->" indicates a de-reference needed at run-time (for pointers). So the logic would have to

a) Dereference address of "list" (*list),

b) Calculate offset to the member "head" (*list).head,

c) Dereference address of head *((*list).head),

d) Calculate offset to the member "next" *((*list).head).next .